# SQL get next entry from known ID in a single query

Tags: sql

I was wondering how would I get the data for the next row in an SQL database, assuming I know the ID for the current entry and the table is ordered by ID.

Normally, when ordering by ID, one would think that to get the prev/next entry, you just need to substract/add 1 to the variable holding the ID, and run the SELECT query with the new ID, but this poses a problem when there are holes in the table, with ID's like so:

13,14,18,21...

And so on.

A way to do it would be by looping in your programming language, running a query and adding 1 every time it runs until it finds a row, but that could be potentially taxing to the database. Is there a way to find it in just a single query?

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking about this being a plausible problem, considering I even thought about it for a second. So I thought of sharing my solution here!

What I would do to solve this, is to create a new query WHERE the new id is less/greater than the old one, like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable t
WHERE t.id > 27
ORDER BY t.id
LIMIT 1
```

By doing this and limiting the results to 1, you can guarantee that you will get the entry that comes after 27.

This should also work for date orderings.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

`Select MIN(myTable.Id)
FROM myTable
WHERE myTable.Id > 27`

Comment: That also works, however, you would also need to wrap every column you want to select in MIN(). It's a viable solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Get the next id number with min(). The next id after, say, 21 would be given by this query.

```
select min(test_id) as next_test_id
from test
where test_id > 21
```

Join that to the original table to get the row for that id number.

```
select *
from test
inner join (select min(test_id) as next_test_id
            from test
            where test_id > 3 ) t2
        on test.test_id = t2.next_test_id
```

Comment: A query inside a query? We need to go deeper! In all seriousness though, this is over complicating the problem. It DOES work, I just don't see any advantage in this solution over the others. It does allow you do select any columns you want without having to MIN() all of them though, but the first suggestion already does that. I guess this could work if for some reason, you didn't want to use LIMIT.